# Get list of file extensions of public.movie UTI

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to create an NSOpenPanel that only looks for movie files. I'd like to do this by looking up the registered movie file extensions using the public.movie UTI. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to retrieve the file extensions of the UTI: you can use the UTI directly.

According to the documentation, the method [`setAllowedFileTypes:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSavePanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSavePanel/setAllowedFileTypes%3a) of the `NSSavePanel` class (superclass of `NSOpenPanel`) accepts UTIs as well as file extensions.

So this should work, without having to wonder about associated file extensions.

```
[yourOpenPanel setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"public.movie"]];
```

Comment: and it was right under my nose the whole time ;-). works perfectly!